# What does Device 0fff mean in lspci output?

Tags: linux, rhel, nvidia

What does **Device 0fff** mean in lspci output? We have Nvidia card installed in a server that runs Red Hat 6. We suspect it is broken but dont know how to confirm it.

1. Is ***Device 0fff*** cofirmation that systems does not recognize the model of this card or perhaps there is something wrong with this card.

   ```
   lspci -nn -v | grep VGA   
   85:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: nVidia Corporation Device       [10de:0fff] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

   lspci -x -s 85:00.00     
   85:00.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 0fff (rev a1) 00: de 10 ff 0f 47 00 10 00 a1 00 00 03 10 00 80 00 10: 00 00 00 f9 0c 00 00 e0 00 00 00 00 0c 00 00 f0 20: 00 00 00 00 01 e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 de 10 4a 09 30: 00 00 00 fa 60 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 01 00 00
   ```

2.Are there any logs that can tell me that Nvidia card is faulty?

Comment: You should try `sudo lspci -v` to get a bit more data.

Comment: Do you have `GK107GL`?

Comment: I cannot check it. It is in the other site and it is not documented.

Comment: Is it old system? In `/usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids` there is an entry for `0fff` device.

Comment: I'd say it is older 5 years. The file you pointed at is from 2011. I cannot find any entry searching for "0fff" using notepad++. Seems I do something wrong?

Comment: The `f` *can* be an indication that the PCI configuration space is not correctly read, which means hardware failure of the PCI bus. But you really need `lspci -nn -v` or better `lspci -x -s 85:00.0` where the last is the address of the device. The `85` is also very suspicious, but you didn't show the rest of the plain `lspci` output ... Also, please don't use screenshots. Insert the output in the text, indented 4 spaces for proper formatting.

Comment: Edited the question as per recommendation. The output of the command is shown as it is, it is not cut. Many thanks!

Comment: Nvidia GK107GL https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC/10de/0fff